# How to apply pos for private geth network using Prysm/Lighthouse?

Tags: lighthouse, prysm

I'm currently running my own private geth network.

Can I use lighthouse or prysm with it to apply pos?

I tried for example,

```
lighthouse \
    --network mydomain.com \
```

but error...

it only has

[possible values: gnosis, goerli, kiln, mainnet, prater, ropsten, sepolia]

```
ERROR powchain: 

Could not check execution client configuration. 
You are probably connecting to your execution client on the wrong port. 

For the Ethereum merge, 
you will need to connect to your execution client on port 8551 rather than 8545.
 This is known as the 'engine API' port and needs to be authenticated if connecting via HTTP. 

error=method not found
```